# Approximate a continuous functions with $C^\infty$ functions in uniform norm.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I have a question concerning the generator of a backwards SDE. Suppose that $f(\omega,t,y,z):\Omega\times\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is almost surely jointly continuous in $(t,y,z)$. Suppose further that $f$ has suitable growth conditions (e.g. linear in $y$ and quadratic in $z$.

In the Kobylanski 2000 paper, it was asserted that there is a sequence $f^{(n)}$ of $C^\infty$ functions such that:

$$f+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\leq f^{(n)} \leq f+\frac{1}{2^n}$$

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to prove the existence of such a sequence. In the said paper, it was said that the existence of this sequence is given by a standard argument of regularisation, but I don't quite see how. Any help or reference would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $f$ is uniformly continuous, you can take $\delta\in (2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n})$ and convolute $f+\delta$ with a mollifier $\eta_\epsilon$. The resulting function is smooth and converges uniformly to $f+\delta$ as $\epsilon\searrow 0$. One can probably make something similar work with the assumption of uniform continuity.